# How to display a div in certain categories in datalife engine?

Tags: javascript, html, css, smarty, datalife-engine

Datalife engine template are build with .tpl files. What i want to do, is to display a div only on a certain category.

So if category ID is == 2 then display the block... Datalife engine has a tag that automaticly does this, but for some reason it's not working right...

I guess php will not work in the TPL files, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i got the right tags

```
[catlist=2] Content goes here [/catlist]
```

The 2 is the ID of the category you want it to display on.

Answer (score 0):

in main.tpl and shortstory.tpl you can use [category=x] tag
in shortstory.tpl and fullstory.tpl you can use [catlist=x] tag